# Multiple organization units from different domains

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have two domains foobar.com and bizbang.com. I have been using foobar.com for all of my GCP activity, but recently purchased bizbang.com and want to start using it for certain projects.

How do I create a project under this domain in GCP? I am currently only seeing foobar.com listed as an organization, and cannot seem to create or find the other organization.

I manage both domains from the same Google Admin account and have BizBang setup as an OU under FooBar.

Is what I want to do possible? If not, does my goal make sense and if so, how can I set it up like I'm asking?

Thank you!

Comment: I strongly recommend you to contact [Contact Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) so you can get assisted there.

Comment: Hi, I have done that. They said I need to contact GCP support, but I don't have paid support, so they suggested I try here.